# Kernel implementation of net netdev_info()

Tags: linux-kernel

From kernel headers `netdevice.h` below.

I searched the source code  for the **implementation** of `netdev_info()` from the path of `kernel/driver/net` and `kernel/include`, but still nothing found. Where is it defined? Any idea?

```c
// include/linux/netdevice.h
void netdev_info(const struct net_device *dev, const char *format, ...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find them so easily because those functions are defined through a macro in [`net/core/dev.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.4/source/net/core/dev.c#L11297)

```c
#define define_netdev_printk_level(func, level)         \
void func(const struct net_device *dev, const char *fmt, ...)   \
{                               \
    struct va_format vaf;                   \
    va_list args;                       \
                                \
    va_start(args, fmt);                    \
                                \
    vaf.fmt = fmt;                      \
    vaf.va = &args;                     \
                                \
    __netdev_printk(level, dev, &vaf);          \
                                \
    va_end(args);                       \
}                               \
EXPORT_SYMBOL(func);

define_netdev_printk_level(netdev_emerg, KERN_EMERG);
define_netdev_printk_level(netdev_alert, KERN_ALERT);
define_netdev_printk_level(netdev_crit, KERN_CRIT);
define_netdev_printk_level(netdev_err, KERN_ERR);
define_netdev_printk_level(netdev_warn, KERN_WARNING);
define_netdev_printk_level(netdev_notice, KERN_NOTICE);
define_netdev_printk_level(netdev_info, KERN_INFO);
```

Comment: Thanks your help. I saw they calling __netdev_printk(), But how to enabled them. I tried **echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk** it seems not work

Comment: Usually `git grep -n -w netdev_info -- include` can give a hint. Maybe makes sense to elaborate in your answer how you found them and how it can be done easily by a newcomer.

Comment: @0andriy I go with the good ol' `grep -R` or VSCode search most of the times since I don't usually have checked out git sources, so I don't think it adds much info :')

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, `grep -R` is very inefficient (up to 100x times?) to go via Git repository. If you have Git index  you shouldn't ever use plain `grep`. Also, having bare repository consumes much **less** storage space (for the preservation, otherwise you can always get the working copy with ease).